# Ajustar gráficos nas extremidades do header

Tags: css, angularjs, html5

Preciso de ajuda para ajustar dois gráficos pie chart nos extremos esquerdo e direito de um header. Toda vez que faço zoom (ctrl e +) eles se desajustam. Configurei o css para que pareça ajustado, mas tão logo dou zoom, tudo fica feio. Desde já agradeço a ajuda. Segue o código:

```js
angular.module('App', ['nvd3']).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 300,
            x: function(d){return d.key;},
            y: function(d){return d.y;},
            showLabels: true,
            duration: 500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
            showLegend: false
        }
    };

    $scope.data = [
        {key: "One", y: 5},
        {key: "Two", y: 2},
        {key: "Three", y: 9},
        {key: "Four", y: 7},
        {key: "Five", y: 4},
    ];
})
```

```css
body{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

header {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:9%;
    width:80%;
    height: 35%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#ffffff), to(#bde8fc)) no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.opts1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.opts2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

h3 {
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <header>
            <div class="opts1">
                <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
                <h3>Features Trends</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="opts2">
                <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
                <h3>Features Trends</h3>
            </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Isso acontece pq seu Css têm valores em % e em PX então quando vc usa o zoom ele recalcula alguns elementos e outros não, ai quebra o layout

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações, @hugocsl. Vc poderia apenas mostrar um exemplo de como eu poderia resolver? Sou novo em programação Web e estou aprendendo tudo sob demanda. Grato!

Comment: Cara repare que aqui `.opts2 { position: absolute; margin-left: 70%;   margin-top: -50px; }` vc usa dois valores para margin, um em PX e outro em %, provavelmente o que está em % vai dar problema quando vc usar o Zoom, vc vai ter que achar para ele um valor em PX que seja equivalente aos 70%, assim vc não terá problemas. Depois vai fazendo isso onde mais precisar. Ou então faz ao contrário, o que pode ser mais indicado para responsividade. Vai colocando % onde for PX etc...